# Can anyone solve this? Is the answer 4 or 7. I'm confused

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

[image]

I'm trying to solve this but I'm confused with different answers. I'm getting 4 but the answer written is 7. Please guide me.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: (What is the *exact* definition of *(number of) prime implicants* you are required to use? Look at the complemented map/"the 0s".)

Answer (score 1):

It's 4 because you're allowed to "wrap around" from the top edge to the bottom edge or from the right edge to the left edge (those moves still represent 1-bit changes because the Gray code is cyclic).

So there is one PI of *3* minterms in the first column, one in the fourth column, one in the third row, and one of 2 minterms in the second row.